# embedding html created by a perl method, in the place it is being called upon

Tags: html, perl, json

I am very new to perl coding,
I am calling a method, which again calls some other method and then generate an html code. I need to embed the htmlcode in my current code, so as to add that to the current html code.

I am calling the method like this

my $test = $frek->xyz();
where xyz generated an html.

now i need to embed the $test in my html, but not finding the way out. 
PLease help

Comment: where is the html you want to add this to?  In a file? an array? a scalar?

Comment: i need it to keep that in the same perl module from where i am calling the method xyz()

Comment: @user430548, what do you mean with **embed in my html**? Otherwise, this looks like a HTML::Mason use case

Comment: As it sounds now, you want to paste html code in between Perl code. That can't be the idea. So again, where is the html code you need the new piece to be embedded in. Do you want to embed the new code in a file, do you want to add the new code in a specific place in an array, do you want to add it to a string variable? You'll have to be a bit more specific if you want an answer that makes sense.

Comment: i want to paste the html code in between perl code, where the html is generated by another perl method.

i need to embed the code in specifc div

Comment: like currently i am trying like this

my $test = $frek->xyz();

and then i need to embed here

<div id='test_results">
  <---- here i need to place the content of $test
</div>

Answer (score 3):

Its not entirely clear what you want, but maybe it's a

- [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Perl) content, or
- something based on [HTML::Mason](http://www.masonbook.com/book/chapter-1.mhtml)
- something based on [HTML::Template](http://html-template.sourceforge.net/article.html)

what would answer your question. What exactly do you try do do?
Can you give a specific example?

---

#### Addendum

After reading another of your comments, I think I got what you are trying to accomplish.

Lets imagine we have a Perl class '`MyClass`' that contains a method `xyz()`:

```
package MyClass;
sub new {
 my $class = shift;
 my $self = { x => shift, y => shift, z => shift };
 bless $self, $class;
 return $self
}
sub xyz {                      # <== here we go
 my ($self) = @_; 
 return $self->{x} * $self->{y} * $self->{z}
}
1;
```

If your Perl program (e.g. `cgitest.pl`) works as a **simple CGI-script**
from a cgi-bin directory, it would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

# here we have html included in source
my $html = q{
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div id='test_results'> #{$test}# </div>
</body>
</html>
};

use MyClass;                         # lets hope it'll be found
my $frek = new MyClass(10,10,10);    # create instance
my $test = $frek->xyz();             # get value

$html =~ s/#{(\$\w+)}#/$1/eeg;       # now replace #{$test}# in html by $test

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; # output modified html to browser
print $html;
```

This would replace the marker `#{$var}#` by the value 
of the actual `$var` and print the resulting html.
Note the (double) `/ee` after the substitution pattern.

But then, if your web site is a **Mason site**, your test.html simply looks like:

```
 <h1>Test</h1>

 <div id='test_results'> <% $test %> </div>

 <!-- Perl initialization code goes below -->

 <%init>
  use MyClass;
  my $frek = new MyClass(10,10,10);
  my $test = $frek->xyz();
 </%init>
```

which can be written similar with a `%perl` code block :

```
<h1>Test</h1>

<%perl>
  use MyClass;
  my $frek = new MyClass(10,10,10);
  my $test = $frek->xyz();
</%perl>

<div id='test_results'> <% $test %> </div>
```

but now, you have intermingled html parts and Perl parts, whereas in
the example above, all Perl code goes below the html. If your Web-
Server is properly [configured for HTML::Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/docs/manual/Mason.html#installation), it will handle 
either of them fine. Mason is available for Windows, Unix and whatever
systems there are.

Regards

rbo